# Can we use $PIPESTATUS with the tee (or pee) command?

Tags: bash, pipe, fifo, tee

In my bash scripts, I often use pipes and would like to know which stage of the pipe was causing the problem in case of errors. The basic structure of such snippets is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ProduceCommand 2>/dev/null | ConsumeCommand >/dev/null 2>&1
PipeErrors=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
[[ "${PipeErrors[0]}" -eq '0' ]] || { HandleErrorInProduceCommand; }
[[ "${PipeErrors[1]}" -eq '0' ]] || { HandleErrorInConsumeCommand; }
```

Now (interestingly enough for the first time) I am in a situation where it would be great if I could use either `tee` or `pee`. But what happens to `$PIPESTATUS` when using these commands? For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

ProduceCommand 2>/dev/null | tee >(ConsumeCommand1) >(ConsumeCommand2) >/dev/null 2>&1
PipeErrors=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

ProduceCommand 2>/dev/null | pee ConsumeCommand1 ConsumeCommand2 2>/dev/null
PipeErrors=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
```

I believe that in both cases `${PipeErrors[0]}` reflects the error status of `ProduceCommand`. Further, it would be logical to assume that `${PipeErrors[1]}` reflects the error status of `tee` or `pee` itself, respectively.

But this leads me into at least two understanding problems:

1. What is the error status (return value) of `tee` or `pee`? I didn't find precise statements about that in the man pages. Do they return a hard-coded error status if one of the consume commands fails, or do they relay the error status of the consume commands somehow (as `ssh` does, for example)? If the former is the case, how can we find out which of the consume commands is the culprit? If the latter is the case, which error status is relayed? Is it simply that of the command which fails first?
2. AFAIK, bash or the `tee` or `pee` command itself, respectively, internally use pipes (fifos) to get `ProduceCommand`'s output to the consume commands. This means that we have a pipe whose (first and in this case, only) receiving side is a pipe itself. This should not influence `$PipeErrors` in the sample code above, but I am really unsure.

Could somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the error status (return value) of `tee`

It's 0 when it was able to copy all the data to all the output files, and >0 if not. See the [spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html). The [GNU coreutils implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html) of `tee` has extra options to ignore errors when writing to *pipes* (as those used to implement `>(...)`):

```
$ seq 1024 | tee >(false) >/dev/null; echo $?
141
$ seq 1024 | tee -p >(false) >/dev/null; echo $?
0
```

There are no options to know *which* of the outputs has failed, if any [1].

---

But your question seems to be rather about whether the exit status of the commands run in `>(..)` process substitutions is reflected in any way in `PIPESTATUS`, or if it *could be* in any way reflected in `PIPESTATUS`.

The answer to that is **No**.

First of all, notice that `>(...)` are more like `... &` background commands than like `...|...` pipeline commands. In a snippet like:

```
... | tee >(cmd ...) | ...; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
```

there's no guarantee that `cmd` has finished at all by the time you run `echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}`.

But they're not exactly like `...&` either as you cannot `wait` for them and cannot obtain their status from `$!` -- except in some limited cases which do *not* include their use with `tee` or other external commands:

```
$ bash -c 'echo 1 | tee >(sleep 2; sed s/1/2/); wait; echo DONE'
1
DONE
$
<after two seconds>
2
```

As you see, both `tee` and the main shell have finished long before the command from `>(...)`.

[1] A command like `pee` which is running the output "subcommands" itself (and is waiting for them to finish) *could* be smarter and reflect in its exit status which of them have failed (e.g. by setting bit 1 for the first, bit 2 for the second, and so on, up to 8 subcommands), but does no such thing either.

Comment: Thank you very much, accepted and +1. That was enlightening. I guess I then can use neither `tee` nor `pee` for my purposes. Even either one of the two disadvantages (background execution, not being able to find out which of the outputs has failed) on its own would prevent that. Thanks also for the link to the spec; too bad that this information is not in the man page. Out of curiosity, I'll check whether it is in the info page at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do:

```bsh
{
  {
    ProduceCommand 2>/dev/null 3>&- ||
      HandleErrorInProduceCommand >&3 3>&-
  } |
    tee >(
      ConsumeCommand1 3>&- ||
        HandleErrorInConsumer1 >&3 3>&-
    ) >(
      ConsumeCommand2 3>&- ||
        HandleErrorInConsumer2 >&3 3>&-
    ) > /dev/null
} 3>&1
```

That handles the error in each of the subshells where the producer and consumers are started.

We duplicate stdout onto fd 3, so can restore the original stdout for the error handlers as we don't want their output if any to go through the pipes.

If you'd rather the error handlers be run within the main shell process (so it can exit it for instance), you could get those subshells to pass the exit status to the parent shell via some command substitution pipe:

```bsh
 producer_status=-1
consumer1_status=-1
consumer2_status=-1
{
  eval "$(
    {
      {
        ProduceCommand 2>/dev/null 4>&-
        echo "producer_status=$?" >&4
      } | tee >(
        ConsumeCommand1 4>&-
        echo "consumer1_status=$?" >&4
      ) >(
        ConsumeCommand2 4>&-
        echo "consumer2_status=$?" >&4
      )
    } 4>&1 >&3 3>&-
  )"
} 3>&1

[ "$producer_status"  -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInProduceCommand
[ "$consumer1_status" -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInConsumer1
[ "$consumer2_status" -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInConsumer2
```

That avoids the `$PIPESTATUS` bashism or you could avoid the `>(...)` kshism and replace them with a normal pipeline:

```bsh
{
  ProduceCommand 2>/dev/null |
    {
      tee /dev/fd/4 |
        ConsumeCommand1 4>&-
    } 4>&1 >&3 3>&- |
      ConsumeCommand2 3>&-
} 3>&1
 producer_status=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
consumer1_status=${PIPESTATUS[1]}
consumer2_status=${PIPESTATUS[2]}

[ "$producer_status"  -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInProduceCommand
[ "$consumer1_status" -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInConsumer1
[ "$consumer2_status" -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInConsumer2
```

Or combine the two approaches and then get standard `sh` syntax and also get access to `tee`'s exit status as a bonus.

```
 producer_status=-1
      tee_status=-1
consumer1_status=-1
consumer2_status=-1

{
  eval "$(
    {
      {
        ProduceCommand 2>/dev/null 4>&-
        echo "producer_status=$?" >&4
      } 3>&- |
        {
          {
            tee /dev/fd/5 4>&-
            echo "tee_status=$?" >&4
          } |
            ConsumeCommand1 4>&-
          echo "consumer1_status=$?" >&4
        } 5>&1 >&3 3>&- |
        ConsumeCommand2 >&3 3>&- 4>&- 
        echo "consumer2_status=$?" >&4
    } 4>&1
  )"
} 3>&1

[ "$producer_status"  -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInProduceCommand
[ "$tee_status"       -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInTee
[ "$consumer1_status" -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInConsumer1
[ "$consumer2_status" -eq 0 ] || HandleErrorInConsumer2
```

Note that `tee` may die of a SIGPIPE if one of the processes exits without reading all the input, which means the other process may also miss some input. So it may be important to also check its exit status.

As already noted by @UncleBilly, with the GNU implementation of `tee`, that can be worked around with the `-p` option (where `tee` ignores SIGPIPE signals and just stops trying to write more data to a pipe when it becomes broken).

With other implementations, you can replace `tee ...` with `(trap '' PIPE; exec tee ...)` to get a similar behaviour (though possibly some error messages about the broken pipes even if `tee` is not aborted).

Comment: Thank you very much for this in-depth answer - +1! But TBH, even after looking at it for an hour, I haven't understood it yet. But I believe I'll be able to understand the answer once I've understood the first example. Therefore I hope you won't mind me asking some questions about that first example (one per comment for clarity). First question: In the process substitutions, shouldn't the pipe symbol (`|`) rather be a shortcut-or (`||`)?

Comment: @Binarus, d'oh. Yes, sorry, those were meant to be `||`, `|` would not make sense. Fixed now.

Comment: I still had some problems with understanding the code, especially the first example, but I've got it now (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672750). Thanks again! By the way, I like `PIPESTATUS`, and I don't like `eval` very much, so your third example probably shows the right way (for me) :-)